# редактор кода на tkinter с диалоговым окном v2

Tags: python, tkinter, ide

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, Label, Button, Text, END

def file_open():
    global open_file
    open_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Python files", "*.py"),("All files", "*.*")))
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    with open(open_file, 'r') as file: 
        text.insert(1.0, file.read())


window = Tk()
window.geometry("310x220") 
 
label = Label(text="Откройте файл который вы хотите просмотреть")
label.pack()
text = Text(height=10)
text.pack()

def save_file():
    with open(open_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(f"{text}")

button = Button(text="Открыть", command=file_open)
button2 = Button(text='Сохранить', command=save_file)   
button.pack(pady=5, padx=5)
button2.pack(pady=5, padx=6)
window.mainloop()
```

(проблема) кнопка \сохранить\ не работает

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

заранее спасибо

Comment: Локальная в функции `file_open` переменная `open_file` не видна в функции `save_file`.

Comment: а как  решить данную проблему

Comment: @pythonist прочитать ответы к вопросу, указанному как дублируемый. В идеале еще почитать что-нибудь про глобальные переменные в Python.

Comment: я добавил глобал но как то что в окне сохранить в файл?

Comment: Кнопка и сохранение у вас работает. Но сохранять нужно не виджет text, а его содержимое: `file.write(text.get(1.0, "end"))`

Comment: Ну правда и если вы не открывали файл, а хотите новый сохранить, то у вас естественно вылетать будет ошибка неинициализированной переменной. Но это уже отдельно обрабатывать нужно - изначально записывать None в open_file, при нажатии на "сохранить" проверять, что там не None, и если None - то показывать диалог сохранения.